# tmux select panel under mac yosemite

Tags: macos, mouse, tmux, osx-yosemite

Yesterday I installed tmux (great piece of software), but I have an annoying problem: while the mouse support seems to work (I can scroll my text using it), I'm unable to select one of the multiple opened panels by clicking on them. In my ~/.tmux.conf file I have the following parameters:

```
set -g mode-mouse on
set -g mouse-resize-pane on
set -g mouse-select-pane on
set -g mouse-select-window on
```

but still, when I have multiple panels opened in my Terminal.app window I'm unable to select one of them by clicking them (as I said, scrolling with the mouse works). I also tried different variants of the options (like using setw) but still no success. I use Yosemite and the standard Terminal app. Tmux is the last version available on homebrew.

any help?

Comment: These options are now replaced with 'set -g mouse on'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that Terminal.app doesn't fully support xterm mouse reporting.

For this reason I use [iTerm.app](https://iterm2.com) as a replacement.